# TFS does not build projects correctly

Tags: tfs

HI
I am trying to build my solution using TFS but it seems to skips the projects which have dependencies. 
e.g Proj B depends on Proj A , then it builds only Proj A and not Proj B.

Also if i try to build the projects individually instead of the solution then it does not create the release folder. It says that the output path is not found.

Any help is much appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is the SLN file in question converted from an older version of Visual Studio?

I've found that sometimes, like when you upgrade from a VS2003 SLN file to a VS2008 SLN file, it fails in MSBuild (which is what TFS is doing essentially).

Try making a new SLN file in VS2008 (or whatever version you're using) with the same project and see if that fixes it...

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click the solution, one option you'll have is **dependencies**.  Make sure that the projects are correctly setup there, even though they may reference each other the dependencies on the solution itself may not be complete or accurate...and this is what MSBuild uses.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the configuration manager and make sure that the build you are running has those projects selected to build.

It may be you are running the Debug configuration for your local build and then running Release on the TFS server and it's not configured the same.